# NativeScript Angular with TypeORM

Tags: webpack, nativescript, typeorm

I'm new in NativeScript.
I tried user SQLite with TypeORM.
When I create a connection I get errors. 
Can you help?

Service code:

```js
    import { createConnection, Connection, ConnectionOptions, getConnection } from "typeorm/browser";
    let driver = require("nativescript-sqlite");
    // let driver = require("nativescript-sqlite");

    @Injectable({
        providedIn: "root"
    })
    export class DatabaseService {
        private dbConnection: Connection;
        constructor() {
            this.initDB();
        }

        /*     async createDb() {
                const db = new driver("limu.db").
            };
         */

        async initDB() {
            try {
                this.dbConnection = await getConnection();
                // this.dbTasksRepository = await this.dbConnection.getRepository(TaskEntity);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('!!!erorr', error);
                await this.createConnection();
                // this.dbTasksRepository = await this.dbConnection.getRepository(TaskEntity);
            }
        }

        private async createConnection() {
            let dbOptions: ConnectionOptions;
            dbOptions = {
                type: "nativescript",
                driver,
                database: "limu.db",
                entities: [
                    TaskEntity
                ],
                logging: ["error", "query", "schema"],
                synchronize: true
            };
            try {
                this.dbConnection = await createConnection(dbOptions);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
Errors:
    WARNING in ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/driver/react-native/ReactNativeDriver.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-sqlite-storage' in '/Users/Compik/Documents/Projects/limu/limu-native/node_modules/typeorm/browser/driver/react-native'
     @ ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/driver/react-native/ReactNativeDriver.js
     @ ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/driver/DriverFactory.js
     @ ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/connection/Connection.js
     @ ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/index.js
     @ ./app/core/database/database.service.ts
     @ ./app/app.component.ts
     @ ./app/app.module.ts
     @ ./main.ts
    Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
    Webpack build done!
    Project successfully prepared (ios)
    Successfully transferred all files on device FD96C24D-FEB6-49AB-BF10-3D3A09F312BD.
    Restarting application on device FD96C24D-FEB6-49AB-BF10-3D3A09F312BD...
    ***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
    Native stack trace:
    1   0x1080c780e NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
    2   0x108119784 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
    3   0x1079cad33 main
    4   0x7fff5227ec25 start
    5   0x1
    JavaScript stack trace:
    ../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js(file: node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js:3:11)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync.js(file: node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync.js:14:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/index.js(file: node_modules/pbkdf2/index.js:24:31)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js(file: node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js:14:16)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/util/StringUtils.js(file: node_modules/typeorm/browser/util/StringUtils.js:1:0)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/naming-strategy/DefaultNamingStrategy.js(file: node_modules/typeorm/browser/naming-strategy/DefaultNamingStrategy.js:1:0)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file:
    JavaScript error:
    file: node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js:3:11: JS ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.process.browser')
    (CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.process.browser')
    at
    ../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js(file: node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js:3:11)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync.js(file: node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync.js:14:30)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/pbkdf2/index.js(file: node_modules/pbkdf2/index.js:24:31)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js(file: node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js:14:16)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../node_modules/typeorm/browser/util/StringUtils.js(file: node_modules/typeorm/browser/util/StringUtils.js:1:0)
    at __webpack_require__(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:750:0)
    at fn(file: src/webpack/bootstrap:120:0)
    at ../
    NativeScript caught signal 6.
    Native Stack:
    1   0x1081183e1 sig_handler(int)
    2   0x7fff5245b42d _sigtramp
    3   0x1
    4   0x7fff5234ba5c abort
    5   0x7fff502497f8 __cxa_bad_cast
    6   0x7fff502499c7 demangling_unexpected_handler()
    7   0x7fff513fbd7c _objc_terminate()
    8   0x7fff50256e97 std::__terminate(void (*)())
    9   0x7fff502568fe __cxa_get_exception_ptr
    10  0x7fff502568c5 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
    11  0x7fff513fbc44 _objc_exception_destructor(void*)
    12  0x1080c7d4f NativeScript::reportFatalErrorBeforeShutdown(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Exception*, bool)
    13  0x108119784 -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
    14  0x1079cad33 main
    15  0x7fff5227ec25 start
    16  0x1
    JS Stack:
```

Comment: Which version of {N} you are using? I'm unsure why it's trying to pickup react native driver while the type is set to nativescript. Can you share a sample project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I use Nativescript 6.4. link to project https://github.com/compishe/typeORMTest.git

Comment: I'm unable to run your project due to various errors with your dependencies, looks like something screwed up when you ran migration.

Answer (score -1):

I found similar problem, check your `webpack` configuration.
Maybe its help you, see [link](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage/issues/32)